# I having troubles with aggregate, but it should work

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data frame called "test" that contains gene names and variances:

```
genes     variance
RERE      0.27742
DLEC1     0.630556
RERE      0.45678
...       ...
```

I would like to create a new data frame with the max variance per gene:

```
genes     variance
RERE      0.45678
DLEC1     0.630556
...       ...
```

I tried:

```
aggregate(test$variance, by = list(test$genes), max)
```

but get this error:

```
Error in Summary.factor(13308L, na.rm = FALSE): 'max' not meaningful for factors
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Seems as if `test$variance` is of type factor, not of type numeric. Check with `str(test)`. In that case, use `test$variance <- as.numeric(as.character(test$variance))` before aggregate.

Comment: Check your original data that you are importing. I'm guessing you have a character string somewhere in your `variance` column, like `"missing"` or something that is causing it to be made a factor.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments, it seems like your "variance" column, which you were expecting to be numeric, is actually a factor.

You can convert it in the `aggregate` command itself, but it is probably a smarter choice to figure out why this conversion happened in the first place.

```
aggregate(test$variance, by = list(test$genes), max)
# Error in Summary.factor(3L, na.rm = FALSE) : 
# ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
aggregate(as.numeric(as.character(test$variance)), 
          by = list(test$genes), max)
#   Group.1        x
# 1   DLEC1 0.630556
# 2    RERE 0.456780
```

#### Sample data

```
test <- structure(
  list(genes = c("RERE", "DLEC1", "RERE"), 
       variance = structure(
         c(1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("0.27742", "0.45678", "0.630556"),
         class = "factor")), .Names = c("genes", "variance"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```